# Simple Parent child Java app

Tags: java, swing

I wishto create a simple Java application which should draw 2 squares - red and blue on a yellow frame.

The appln contains a window(JFrame) that has a contentPane(JPanel) added as a child. I have added the 2 squares as a child to the JFrame

```
/**
Squares' container
------------------
This file contiains 2 small squares - red and blue. The user can drag
these squares in the panel. If the user drags these squares out of the
panel, the square is lost forever.
*/

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class sqsCont {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setVisible(true);
    sqsContPanel myPanel = new sqsContPanel();
    window.setBounds(0,0,500,250);
    window.getContentPane().add(myPanel);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(window.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);      
}
}

/**
Contains 2 squares red and blue side-by-side on 
*/
class sqsContPanel extends JPanel{
mySquare redSq;
mySquare blueSq;

public sqsContPanel() {
    //setBounds(0,0,500,250);
    redSq = new mySquare(Color.RED);
    blueSq = new mySquare(Color.BLUE);
    add(redSq);
    add(blueSq);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
}
}

/**
Squares
*/
class mySquare extends JComponent{
int myWidth = 50;
int myHeight = 50;
Color myColor;

/**
    myColor = color of the square
*/
public mySquare(Color myColor) {
    this.myColor = myColor;     
    if(myColor == Color.RED) {
        setBounds(10,10,10+myWidth,10+myHeight);
    } else {
        setBounds(20+myWidth,10,10+myWidth,10+myHeight);
    }
    setVisible(true);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (myColor == Color.RED){
        setBackground(Color.RED);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(10,10,10+myWidth,10+myHeight);
    } else {
        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(20+myWidth,10,10+myWidth,10+myHeight);   
    }
}
}
```

The code generates the window with yellow frame. However, the squares are not visible.

Can anyone spot what I am missing in this code, or what I should do differently for this appln to work properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing and AWT use layout managers to determine where components are put inside containers (see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html). In your case you seem to be trying to place components manually by calling setBounds. For that to work you have to replace the default layout manager for your panel like this:

```
public sqsContPanel() {
    setLayout(null);
    ....
```

Once you have done that then your square components will be where you want them. You will not be able to see your blue square as the background colour is never painted. This is because g.fillRect(...) uses coordinates local to the current component. You are calling it like this:

```
        g.fillRect(20 + myWidth, 10, 10 + myWidth, 10 + myHeight);
```

20 + myWidth = 70. The width of the component is 60. Therefore nothing gets drawn. You can replace paintComponent in the mySquare class with this simpler version to fix the problem:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(myColor);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 10 + myWidth, 10 + myHeight);
}
```

Style note: In Java the convention is for all class names start with an upper case letter. So mySquare should be MySquare.

Comment: Thanks for resolving my issues patiently :)

Answer (score 1):

You should do all operations changing the GUI inside the AWT event dispatch thread (EDT), including adding components.

In your case, this is simple:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() {
       JFrame window = new JFrame();
       window.setVisible(true);
       sqsContPanel myPanel = new sqsContPanel();
       window.setBounds(0,0,500,250);
       window.getContentPane().add(myPanel);
       window.setDefaultCloseOperation(window.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   }});
}
```

By the way, I would first add components and setup, and only as the last operation use `setVisible(true)`.

Comment: Thanks for that Russ and Paulo. btw I now understand flowlayout. For that i removed [code]setbounds()[\code] and added [code] setPreferredSize(new Dimension(myWidth, myHeight))[\code] in MySquares class.(for future references)

Comment: @Edwards: For inline code, use backticks (``), then it will be formatted like source code (and not interpreted).